# Catkin make with Hydro issues?

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm trying to build some code in Hydro, and I'm having some trouble. Catkin was working well with the code the other day, and now I'm having issues for some reason. I have not altered any of the code in `p2os`, nor have I altered `vanderbilt-ros-pkg`, so it should at least build those two...

I tried to make a new catkin workspace, and the `devel` directory was not created. Did I screw up some environment variables, or is this just a difference in Hydro? Here's some output.

```
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ catkin_init_workspace 
Creating symlink "/home/allenh1/ros_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  p2os  rqt_p2os_controller  vanderbilt-ros-pkg
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ cd ../
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/allenh1/ros_ws
Source space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/allenh1/ros_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/allenh1/ros_ws/build"
####
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws$ ls
build  src
```

---

I have done your suggestions to know avail before posting the output above, but I reproduced the process below (in its entirety).

```
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ rm  -f CMakeLists.txt && rm -rf ../build
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ ls
p2os  rqt_p2os_controller  vanderbilt-ros-pkg
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ cd p2os
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src/p2os$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  p2os_dashboard  p2os_launch  p2os_urdf  stack.xml
Makefile        p2os_driver     p2os_teleop  README.md
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src/p2os$ cd p2os_driver
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src/p2os/p2os_driver$ ls
CMakeLists.txt         include   manifest.xml  p2os-joystick-teleop.xml  src
CMakeLists.txt.backup  Makefile  msg           package.xml
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src/p2os/p2os_driver$ cd ~/ros_ws/src
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ ls
p2os  rqt_p2os_controller  vanderbilt-ros-pkg
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ ls ../
src
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ catkin_init_workspace
Creating symlink "/home/allenh1/ros_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  p2os  rqt_p2os_controller  vanderbilt-ros-pkg
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws/src$ cd ../
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws$ ls
src
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/allenh1/ros_ws
Source space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/allenh1/ros_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/allenh1/ros_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/allenh1/ros_ws/install" in "/home/allenh1/ros_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.4") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX


-- Build files have been written to: /home/allenh1/ros_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/allenh1/ros_ws/build"
####
allenh1@allenh1-Aspire-1830T:~/ros_ws$ ls
build  src
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69586/catkin-make-with-hydro-issues?/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-29**:
Your output indicated that catkin_make was not even executing cmake. Please remove the build folder, run catkin_make again and post the full output of that command.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-29**:
One minor thing: you don't have to call `catkin_init_workspace` explicitly. It will happen automatically when invoking `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-29**:
Are you sure that you are using the latest versions of packages? The cmake output seems to lack a lot of information between `Found PythonInterp` and `Configuring done`. You might want to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Can you also run the following command to list all packages: python -c "import catkin_pkg.packages; print(catkin_pkg.packages.find_packages('.').keys())"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try removing the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `src` folder, as well as the `build` folder and run `catkin_make` again.

Also assert that you have the correct version of things in those folders, especially check that there are `package.xml`'s there, because it seems like `catkin_make` is not finding any packages, and the above output looks like that is not the first time you've run on an empty workspace with that build folder.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2